# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException at MainFragment

Tags: android, android-webview, android-assets

recently I found out that my application crashes on some devices. Here is the crash:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.zippyshare.search.free.fragment.MainFragment$3.loadFromAssetsWhite(MainFragment.java:501)
   at com.zippyshare.search.free.fragment.MainFragment$3.shouldInterceptRequest(MainFragment.java:477)
   at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.shouldInterceptRequest(CallbackProxy.java:1463)
   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.shouldInterceptRequest(BrowserFrame.java:964)
   at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java)
   at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:113)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:1133)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Here is the crashing coode:

```
    private WebResourceResponse loadFromAssetsWhite(String assetPath, String mimeType, String encoding){

501 line ------>AssetManager assetManager = getActivity().getAssets();
                InputStream input;
                try {
                    input = assetManager.open("search-white.png");
                    return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, input);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("WEB-APP", "Error loading " + assetPath + " from assets: " +
                            e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                return null;
            }
```

and here is a call for that method:

```
if (webViewUrl != null && webViewUrl.contains("results.html")) {
                            return loadFromAssetsBlack("", "", "");
                        } else {
    477 line--------------->return loadFromAssetsWhite("", "", "");
                        }
```

Full WebViewClient code:

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
            {
                private boolean mSuccess = true;

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
                    Logcat.d("Resource(PRE) URL: "+url);
                    if (url.contains("adcash.com")){
                        return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "utf-8",
                                new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes()));
                    } else if (url.equals("search_box_icon.png")) {
                        isUrlReady = false;
                        webViewUrl = null;
                        try {
                            MainActivity.mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    webViewUrl = webView.getUrl();
                                    isUrlReady = true;
                                }
                            });

                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            isUrlReady = true;
                        }
                        while(!isUrlReady);
                        isUrlReady = false;
                        if (webViewUrl != null && webViewUrl.contains("results.html")) {
                            return loadFromAssetsBlack("", "", "");
                        } else {
                            return loadFromAssetsWhite("", "", "");
                        }
                    }

                    Logcat.d("Resource(POST) URL: "+url);
                    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
                }
    private WebResourceResponse loadFromAssetsBlack(String assetPath, String mimeType, String encoding){

                    AssetManager assetManager = getActivity().getAssets();
                    InputStream input;
                    try {
                        input = assetManager.open("search-black.png");
                        return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, input);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("WEB-APP", "Error loading " + assetPath + " from assets: " +
                                e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                    return null;
                }



    private WebResourceResponse loadFromAssetsWhite(String assetPath, String mimeType, String encoding){

            AssetManager assetManager = getActivity().getAssets();
            InputStream input;
            try {
                input = assetManager.open("search-white.png");
                return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, input);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("WEB-APP", "Error loading " + assetPath + " from assets: " +
                        e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

If you need more details, you can check Crashalytics report: http://crashes.to/s/e0975fe822c
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Is that called in the very beginning of the Fragment lifecycle, or the end, or both?  It looks like it's the call to `getActivity()` on a null context that's causing the NPE.

Comment: Hello @daniel, sorry but I doenst understand your question as I'm kinda new to coding. How can i determine is it happens in beginning or at the end of cycle?

Comment: Well, if you called it too early it could cause getActivity() to return null, but that's probably not the case here.  Can you post more of your Fragment code, it's hard to tell what's going on with the small amount of code there.

Comment: @DanielNugent here is full code of WebViewClient. Maybe it helps:

http://pastebin.com/j5v5Uj7F

Comment: Try to pass the context as variable in the method and use that context inside method instead of getActivity(),If any case this fails them create a static reference of context in your main  activity and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix as suggested @Chandra:

```
private WebResourceResponse loadFromAssetsWhite(String assetPath, String mimeType, String encoding){
            Context context = getActivity();
            if(context == null) {
                context = MainActivity.mainActivity;
            }
            AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
            InputStream input;
            try {
                input = assetManager.open("search-white.png");
                return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, input);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("WEB-APP", "Error loading " + assetPath + " from assets: " +
                        e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return null;
        }
```